# Impala Cannot access Hive Database

Tags: hive, hql, impala

I have created a database using hql , and is being created there . But I am not able to use that database from an impala application . But the table exists in the hive and we ca query it there . This issue is seen only for some newly created tables. Can somebody please help

Answer (score 1):

issue the following command in impala shell.

```
invalidate metadata;
```

This will load the metadata information to the impala coordinator node you are connected to.

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html